# What is the best way to determine application root directory?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to get all dlls in my application root directory. What is the best way to do that?

```
string root = Application.StartupPath;
```

Or,

```
string root = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FullName;
```

And after that,

```
Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.dll");
```

Which way is better? Are there better ways?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is my go to way of doing so.

However:

`Application.StartupPath` gets the directory of your executable

`AppDomain.BaseDirectory` gets the directory used to resolve assemblies

Since they can be different, perhaps you want to use Application.StartupPath, unless you care about assembly resolution.

Comment: Application.StartupPath will be effected by "Working Directory" if it's set in the exe shortcut, or the process is started from another apps. I didn't realized it until much later, which had cost me days of sleepless night to troubleshoot what went wrong.

Comment: I have had to downvote as in .NET 8 at least "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" will often return a temporary AppData folder and not the EXE folder. So BaseDirectory is not a consistent way to get exe root.

Comment: What do you mean by often? What does that depend on. At any case thanks for pointing out the potential change

Answer (score 26):

It depends. If you want the directory of the EXE that started the application, then either of your two examples will work. Remember though, that .NET is very flexible, and it could be that another application has linked to your EXE and is calling it, possibly from another directory.

That doesn't happen very often and you would probably have written if it did, but it is a possibility. Because of that, I prefer to specify which assembly I am interested in and get the directory from that. Then I know that I am getting all of the DLLs in the same directory as that specific assembly. For example, if you have an application MyApp.exe with a class in it MyApp.MyClass, then you would do this;

```
string root = string.Empty;
Assembly ass = Assembly.GetAssembly( typeof( MyApp.MyClass ) );
if ( ass != null )
{
   root = ass.Location;
}
```

Comment: I especially like determining my ass.Location ;D

Comment: I pretend to think that the variable ass stands for the Assembly word Lol.

Comment: I guess the joke must have been on an aeroplane on December 9th, 2016

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question but I always used to use:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

However, looking at the solutions in here I think some simple tests need to be done:

```
var r = new List<long>();
var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();

s.Restart();
string root1 = Application.StartupPath;
r.Add(s.ElapsedTicks);

s.Restart();
string root2 = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
r.Add(s.ElapsedTicks);

s.Restart();
string root3 = Path.GetDirectoryName(new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FullName);
r.Add(s.ElapsedTicks);

s.Restart();
string root4 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
r.Add(s.ElapsedTicks);

s.Restart();
string root5 = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly( typeof( Form1 ) ).Location);
r.Add(s.ElapsedTicks);
```

The results in ticks:

- 49
- 306
- 166
- 26
- 201

So it seems `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the application root folder path use below code sample.

```
string path =new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName
```

Comment: I don't *think* this is what OP meant by the root directory, although it *was* five years ago so it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: I don't know if that answer is related to the ask, but it solve my problem.

Comment: In development env. it will work fine but in production, it wont work.

Comment: System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, just in case if other people which library it's derived from.

Answer (score 0):

I use

`Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath)`

The Assembly.Location will point to the shadow copy if you use shadow copying, so using CodeBase is a better option, but CodeBase is a Url.