# What is the WPF equivalent to "System.Windows.Forms.Application.X" for obtaining startup path, app data path, etc.?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm converting a windows forms application to a WPF application.  Is there a way to obtain things like, Startup Path, User App Data Path, Common App Data Path, etc. without referencing System.Windows.Forms?

Previously, I used `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath`, but the `System.Windows.Application.Current` object doesn't contain the same information.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might want to look at [`System.Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx).

The values of the [`SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum are numerous:

```
ApplicationData
CommonApplicationData
CommonProgramFiles
Cookies
Desktop
DesktopDirectory
Favorites
History
InternetCache
LocalApplicationData
MyComputer
MyDocuments
MyMusic
MyPictures
Personal
ProgramFiles
Programs
Recent
SendTo
StartMenu
Startup
System
Templates
```

Is that helpful?

Answer (score 6):

this will help

for Application.StartupPath use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx

Comment: Considering the OP's example was about StartupPath, I believe this should be the accepted answer. SpecialFolder.Startup is something *completely* different.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Environment class to get all types of system information.  For directories, use the Environment.GetFolderPath method.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

Comment: Don't use this to store user data, as the Summery states: `The user's profile folder. Applications should not create files or folders at this level; they should put their data under the locations referred to by System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData. Added in the .NET Framework 4.`

Answer (score 0):

I understand and agree that referencing to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` looks ugly but I think that's better then decrease code re-use and re-invent bicycle instead just one more reference.

I use for example `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductVersion` in my console apps, don't like that but think that's the lesser evil..

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362790/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-application-root-directory) question on SO