# How to fix open file dialog not filtering in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

This is the code i made

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
            Nullable<bool> result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Lua scripts (*.lua)|*.lua|Txt Scripts (*.txt*)|*.txt";
            openFileDialog.Title = "Save Scripts";
            if (result == true)
            {
                TextEditor.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName);
            }
```

Comment: Would it help to set the filter _before_ you show the dialog? This might be a simple typo.

Comment: Why are you mixing WPF and WinForms types? (Don't use `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath` in WPF, [use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603417/159145)).

Comment: `Title = "Save Scripts";` <-- Shouldn't this be "**Open** script file" instead? You have an `OpenFileDialog`, not a `SaveFileDialog`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You're calling `.ShowDialog()` **before** your code sets `openFileDialog.Filter = "Lua scripts (*.lua)|*.lua|Txt Scripts (*.txt*)|*.txt";`.
- Also, don't use `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath` in WPF, [use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603417/159145) - or just `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.
- IMO, you should always have an `"All files (*.*)"` filter option for the benefit of users with non-standard file extensions.
- You can simplify `if (result == true)` to just `if (result ?? false)`.
- Note that `OpenFileDialog` doesn't guarantee that the file in `OpenFileDialog.FileName` actually exists or is valid, you need to do that yourself (e.g. `if( File.Exists(...) ) { ... }`).

Rearrange your lines like so:

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;

const String FILTER_LUA = "Lua scripts (*.lua)|*.lua";
const String FILTER_TXT = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
const String FILTER_ALL = "All files (*.*)|*";

// ...

OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog()
{
//  InitialDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
    InitialDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
    Filter           = FILTER_LUA + "|" + FILTER_TXT + "|" + FILTER_ALL,
    Title            = "Open script file"
};

Boolean? result = ofd.ShowDialog();

if( ( result ?? false ) && File.Exists( ofd.FileName ) )
{
    String fileText = File.ReadAllText( ofd.FileName ); 
    this.TextEditor.Text = fileText;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dai, have a nice day/night.