# How to add current working directory in a winformapplication

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Currently I have hard coded the file location in a config file, but instead I want to pick up that from the current running directory of the application.

Is there a way arround?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to determine application root directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362790/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-application-root-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

Environment.CurrentDirectory property.

Please refer link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx