# Getting relative path of file?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have a file called settings.xml located at:

`c:\solution1\solution1\data\settings.xml`

Right now, I am doing:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\solution1\solution1\settings.xml");
```

I can't figure how to do it with a relative path.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362790/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-application-root-directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean relative to your executable, you can use

```
string exeLocation = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
```

Note the frequently suggested

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

will get the path where the assembly is *currently located*, which can be different e.g. if a shadow copy is being executed.

You can use

```
string exeDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(exeLocation);
```

to get the executable's directory.

If you want to find a file that is in a *data* directory under your install location, you could do

```
string dataFile = Path.Combine(exeDir, "data\settings.xml");
```

Note that under Windows Vista and later, you will not have *write* access by default to a directory located under your install directory.

Comment: In my case, my Data directory is not underneath my exe directory

Comment: What then do you want the Data directory to be relative *to*?

Comment: I changed the Build Action to Content and Copied the File if newer, so I am now using the exe directory path.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get relative to the current directory it was started from

```
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Comment: The current directory can change (for example by using a file dialog). This solution would work only by accident, not by principle.

Comment: Just because it changes does not mean that isn't desired.